# Detecting peaks in python plots

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

My data file is shared in the following link.

We can plot this data using the following script.

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cbook as cbook

def read_datafile(file_name):

    data = np.loadtxt(file_name, delimiter=',')
    return data

data = read_datafile('mah_data.csv')


fig = plt.figure()

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax1.set_title("Data")    
ax1.set_xlabel('t')
ax1.set_ylabel('s')

ax1.plot(x,y, c='r', label='My data')

leg = ax1.legend()

plt.show()
```

How can we detect peaks in python? I can't find a suitable peak detection algorithm in Python.

Comment: Please add sample dataset in the question, I couldn't access to the google drive.

Comment: What are `x` and `y`? Presumably, they're based on the `data` array, but you don't define them in the code you've posted thus far.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the **argrelextrema** function in **scipy.signal** to return the indices of the local maxima or local minima of an array. This works for multi-dimensional arrays as well by specifying the axis.

```
from scipy.signal import argrelextrema

ind_max = argrelextrema(z, np.greater) # indices of the local maxima
ind_min = argrelextrema(z, np.less)  # indices of the local minima

maxvals = z[ind_max]
minvals = z[ind_min]
```

More specifically, one can use the **argrelmax** or **argrelmin** to find the local maximas or local minimas. This also works for multi dimensional arrays using the axis argument.

```
from scipy.signal import argrelmax, argrelmin

ind_max = argrelmax(z, np.greater) # indices of the local maxima
ind_min = argrelmin(z, np.less)  # indices of the local minima

maxvals = z[ind_max]
minvals = z[ind_min]
```

For more details, one can refer to this link: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/signal.html#peak-finding

Answer (score 3):

Try using peakutil (http://pythonhosted.org/PeakUtils/). Here is my solution to your question using peakutil.

```
import pandas as pd
import peakutils
data = pd.read_csv("mah_data.csv", header=None)
ts = data[0:10000][1] # Get the second column in the csv file
print(ts[0:10]) # Print the first 10 rows, for quick testing
# check peakutils for all the parameters.
# indices are the index of the points where peaks appear
indices = peakutils.indexes(ts, thres=0.4, min_dist=1000)
print(indices)
```

You should also checkout peak finding in scipy (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.find_peaks_cwt.html)

Comment: You can checkout https://plot.ly/python/peak-finding/ for an example of plotting the data and identifying the peaks.

Answer (score 1):

Try the `findpeaks` library.

```
pip install findpeaks
```

I can not find the data attached but suppose the data is a vector and stored in data:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv("mah_data.csv", header=None).values

# Import library
from findpeaks import findpeaks

# If the resolution of your data is low, I would recommend the ``lookahead`` parameter, and if your data is "bumpy", also the ``smooth`` parameter.
fp = findpeaks(lookahead=1, interpolate=10)
# Find peaks
results = fp.fit(data)
# Make plot
fp.plot()

# Results with respect to original input data.
results['df']

# Results based on interpolated smoothed data.
results['df_interp']
```